# Is the below assertion true? Why?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $n\in N$,  $a_n$ be a real sequence such that $|a_{n+1}-a_n|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, then $a_n$ is convergent in $R$.

Comment: HINT: Look at the sequence of [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).

Comment: Thank you. Got your point. $|H_{n+1}-H_n|$ tends to zero as n tends to infinite but $H_n$ is not convergent.

Comment: Exactly; you’re welcome.

Comment: The converse is provable and true!

Comment: Or how about: if $a_n$ converges, it is absolutely convergent?